# UI design when root and child nodes are reused

Tags: usability, gui-design, hierarchy

Imagine I have structure where root and child nodes are same but intermediate nodes are different. Each node represents one data class with multiple attributes.

Flow 1

```
XY
-Y
--YY
----XYZ
```

Flow2

```
XY
-X
--XX
---XYZ
```

I want to design a user interface in such a way that user can start with Flow 1 from top to bottom i.e. XY to XYZ and reuse XYZ in flow 2 and complete it from bottom to top i.e. from XYZ to X (XY is not required as it was already created in flow 1). Or User first completes the flow 2 from top to down and complete flow 1 from bottom to top. I want to provide a flexibility to the user to follow any flow.

Comment: I find abstract questions like this to be practically impossible to answer.  **The design is all about the context**: what is your app actually doing?

Comment: I agree with dan1111. Can you please replace 'XY', 'Y', etc. with actual meaningful examples?

Comment: Agreed - a little more detail will be necessary to help diagnose your situation.